# jQuery Cookie that Saves the Order of a Group of Divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies

Say i have 4 div's in an enclosing div. The div's inside have classes of div1, div2, div3, div4.

I want to save the order of these div's and then load the correct order the next time the page loads. (e.g. http://jquery-howto.blogspot.com/2010/09/jquery-cookies-getsetdelete-plugin.html)

So. My question is. What is the best way to turn this list of divs into an array to be stored in a cookie?

Code snippets would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: You just want to save the orders, not the content? Can't you just extract the ordered list of class names and save that as a string?

Comment: I was planning on saving just the orders, and then when the page loads again later using jQuery to order them properly.

Would you be able to show some example code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like:

```
var order = [];
$('#containerDiv').children().each(function() {
    order.push($(this).attr('class'));
});
var orderString = order.join(","); // this will be div1,div2,div3 etc..
```

Comment: That will get me started. Thanks.